# How to loop through the multiple items in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

How can I loop through items in django template on the following way

```
    {% for brand in categories%}
    <div class="brand-col">
        <figure class="brand-wrapper">
            <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="Brand" width="410" height="186" /> (item1)
        </figure>
         <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="Brand" width="410" height="186" /> (item2)
        </figure>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    

<div class="brand-col">
        <figure class="brand-wrapper">
            <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="Brand" width="410" height="186" /> (item3)
        </figure>
         <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="Brand" width="410" height="186" /> (item4)
        </figure>
    </div>

<div class="brand-col">
        <figure class="brand-wrapper">
            <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="Brand" width="410" height="186" /> (item5)
        </figure>
         <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="Brand" width="410" height="186" /> (item6)
        </figure>
    </div>
```

**Reference:** (item number inside bracket is just for reference)
Here, first I want to loop 1 and loop 2 on  **figure** tag and again I want to loop entire **div** and loop 3 and loop 4 inside the **div on figure tag**.

I tried to do with cycle, but no luck. Any help will be highly  appreciated.

Comment: This question lacks clarity unfortunately. What are item 1 and 2 and so on?

Comment: Hi Yusuf, thank your for the comment. Actually I tried to represent loop count as item1, so on and so forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline of how this can be achieved. Have an enumerated object in your view function such as

```
enumerated_brands = enumerate(categories)
```

Then pass this object to the context variable in the render method for the return statement of your view function such as:

```
def brand_view(request,...):
    ...
    enumerated_brands = enumerate(categories)
    ...
    return render(..., context={'enumerated_brands': enumerated_brands})
```

Then, use the enumerated_brands in your html file with:

```
{% for brand in brands %} 
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %} 
<div class="brand-col"> 
{% endif %} 
<figure class="brand-wrapper"> 
<img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="{{brand.name}}" width="410" height="186" /> 
</figure> 
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 or forloop.last %} 
</div> 
{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I got this error:

Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:  

Could not parse the remainder: '(index+1)' from '(index+1)'

Comment: Try using this instead: `{% if index+1|modulo:3 == 0 %}`

Comment: Still same problem:

Exception Type:  TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:  

Could not parse some characters: index|+1||modulo:3

Comment: You are typing it incorrectly I think. Have you copy and pasted my reply which I edited above?

Comment: Also can you try:
`{% if index|add:"1"|divisibleby:3 %}`

Comment: Figure is looping but its outside div.

I want to loop like this:
https://imgur.com/hO0VJCz

But its looping like this:
https://imgur.com/uGbC4u2

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to take one figure at a time for the loop index and then a div for the third element in the cycle. This should not be so difficult to achieve with the code given above though. Is not replacing two figure tags with just one sufficient?

Comment: Just carry the div tag outside the for loop and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I want to loop figure inside div for two times and again loop the div where figure inside div will be looped again two times.

Comment: div tag outside for lopp is not working

Comment: Ok, will try but I need some time.

Comment: I have made an edit to the code up in my original reply. Can you please take a look?

Comment: { endif }
{% else %} here is error.

I updated with {% endif %} {%empty%}

with else it throws following error:

Invalid block tag on line 55: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: For your further clarification I have edited the question, could you please check?

Comment: I understood what you are trying to achieve. Sorry, I forgot to close the if tag in my reply. Can you try again with the edited answer above?

Comment: Yes, I tried unfortunately its not printing anything. Entire div is no visible.

Comment: With this:
https://imgur.com/2cNwba9

I am getting this result:
https://imgur.com/tbSPGGv

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. With your resource,I found the solution.

Comment: Can you accept my answer to mark this as closed?

Comment: Edit the answer to this:


   
{% for brand in brands %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
        <div class="brand-col">
        {% endif %}
        <figure class="brand-wrapper">
            <img src="{{brand.product_feature_image.image.url}}" alt="{{brand.name}}" width="410" height="186" />
        </figure>
        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 or forloop.last %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    
    
    {% endfor %}

I will close then.

Comment: I just did. Thanks.

Comment: I am stuck with Django MPTT since long, if you could help. I will be thankful. Question is already asked

Comment: Please provide a link to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70569395/how-to-display-child-element-in-django-mptt

Here it is. Thank you